# Convergence in probability of this sum

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Consider $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ with
>   $P(X_k=1)=1/k^{1/2}$ and the sequence $$ Z_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k. $$
>
> *Question:* Does it hold that $Z_n\to0$ in probability, as $n\to\infty$?

My intuition says yes because $Z_n$ appears to be "of the same order" as
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n^{2/3}k^{1/2}} \le \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^{7/6}}\to0,\text{ as $n\to\infty$,}
$$
where the latter convergence follows since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^{7/6}<\infty$ (Riemann-Zeta function).

So far a proof eludes me, is my intuition perhaps wrong?

Edit: Note that the $X_i$ are not necessarily uncorrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MArkov's inequality,
\begin{align}
P(Z_n > \epsilon) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon} E[Z_n] 
= \frac{1}{n \epsilon}\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{1}{k^{1/2}}
\end{align}
So the RHS is the sum you wrote in the question and therefore it converges to zero, for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Ok, somebody else already wrote that in the comment. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: I encourage you to keep your answer. (+1) It is always better to have an answer than a comment, although my own unnecessary fastidiousness usually discourages me to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think it even converges strongly in $L^2$.

We have (using Cauchy-Schwarz)
$$
\mathbb{E} |Z_n|^2 = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i,j = 1}^n \mathbb{E} (X_i X_j) \leq 
\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n (\mathbb{E} X_i^2)^{1/2} (\mathbb{E} X_j^2)^{1/2} = 
\frac{1}{n^2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^{1/4}} \right)^2 \leq C \frac{1}{n^2} n^{2(1-1/4)} = C n^{-1/2}.
$$

Comment: (+1) Generalizing this computation, we may go even further by showing that $Z_n \to 0$ in $L^p$ for any $p<\infty$: By Hölder's inequality, $$\mathbf{E}[Z_n^m]\leq\frac{1}{n^m}\sum_{i_1,\cdots,i_m=1}^{n}(\mathbf{E}X_{i_1})^{1/m}\cdots(\mathbf{E}X_{i_m})^{1/m}=\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^{1/2m}}\right)^m,$$which converges to $0$ by Stolz–Cesàro theorem.

Comment: that's a good point, thanks! In fact, the last sum in your remark is still of order $n^{-1/2}$ (as can be seen by a small computation), since $\sum_{i=1}^n i^{-\alpha} \leq C n^{1-\alpha} $ with $\alpha>0$ (just by using the monotoncity of $n^{-\alpha}$ and comparing with the integral of $x^{-\alpha}$ over $[1,n]$ ) . We thus get that $\mathbb{E} Z_n^m \leq C n^{-m} n^{ m(1-1/2m) } = C n^{-1/2}$.